# Sqoop Permission Issue when running inside Map Reduce Code

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, sqoop

I am trying to invoke Sqoop through a map reduce program using

```
Sqoop.runTool(arguments,_conf);
```

When executing, I receive the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create temporary directory: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/a609226c19d65f561dd7035c00d318f6; check for a directory permissions issue on /tmp.
```

I have set the permissions on /tmp and it's subdirectories in HDFS  to 777

I can invoke the same command fine through command line using `sudo -u hdfs sqoop ...`

This is Cloudera's hadoop distirbution and I am running the job as hdfs user.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it (1) was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced, (2) has no response from asker who was last active in 2013, (3) has no accepted nor useful answers, (4) has attracted a non-answer 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the /tmp directory in HDFS, but rather then /tmp directory on the local file system - whats the permissions on that directory (and would also explain why it works when you 'sudo' the command)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I changed the permissions of the /tmp directory to 777, but i'm getting the still error. I'm sure the location it is referring to is on the HDFS.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace into your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Just clean `/tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile` floder it works

Comment: The question is about permissions. Did you get (and solve) the same error?